# Ubuntu Studio 19.10 in VMWare 15 player problem

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, ubuntu-studio

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu Studio 19.10 in VM Ware player 15, and i have also tried VirtualBox. Vmware will get to Grub, i select "try Ubuntu Studio" and it comes up with the booting logo for Ubuntu Studio and then loads to a black screen but it loads the gnome bar at the top but you cant click on anything. VirtualBox just loads to a black screen. The VM's have 2 cpu's, 2gb of ram, and vmware had 1gb of video, and virtualbox had the max of 128mb. Regular Ubuntu loads fine in the same vm so i dont know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio#Known_Problems), Ubuntu Studio does not support being run in a virtual machine as virtual machines are known to have problems with the Low Latency kernel.